# How do I get the number of cycles in a grid. Is there a formula?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

So does anyone know the formula in order to get the number of cycles, I'm not directly asking for the answer but at least someone guides me on how to get a cycle given a grid such as an image above.

Comment: related [OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A140517). As of now the number was only computed for $n \leq 20$.

Comment: @plshelp Seems like a complete answer.

Comment: @plshelp, for $n\le 26$ as shown [here](http://oeis.org/A140517/b140517.txt).